# Help to identify python module (preprocessor?) "python -m dg"

Tags: python

On the background of this image [image] you can find some code, that looks like written in extended python dialect, which have to be processed with “python -m dg” to get “normal” python code.
Google has no results for “python -m dg” query, and yandex.ru has only one page in cache, which briefly mention one example

```
python  -m dg  <<< 'sum $ map int $ str 2 ** 1000'
```

which seems to be equivalent of

```
sum(map(int, str(2**1000)))
```

Do you know what this is all about? I want to take a look at this tool, but can't find any links…

Comment: That's the solution to [Problem #16](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=16) of Project Euler... :D

Comment: Note: Translation of the message in foreground: `GNU/Linux is blocked. Proprietary software was detected on your PC, so it has been blocked by Richard Stallman. To unblock GNU/Linux, send an SMS with text "proprietarysoftwaresucks" to number 5555 and input the confirmation code in the field below. Unblock. Warning! Attempt to reinstall GNU/Linux will lead to data loss.` This is a parody of a "Trojan.Winlock"-type ransomware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dg is a custom language, **that compiles to CPython 3.4 (or latest) bytecode.**

Link to project on GitHub: https://github.com/pyos/dg

Comment: @AlexLaskin: This is the correct answer, you should accept it. Actually it now compiles to CPython 3.3 / 3.4 bytecode. The provided link was also correct, but unfortunately the project has been deleted. I had forked it and you can find it here: https://github.com/rubik/dg

Comment: @rubik the project is not deleted now.

Comment: It was restored shortly after. Now it's being actively developed.

Answer (score 4):

Fascinating — but, as the other answers note, an utterly unreleased and unknown language. How did you ever find it in the background of that screenshot? I had to brighten the image in the GIMP to see what you were talking about.

The dialect is slightly Pythonic — it uses `__init__()` for object initiation, and seems to have something like Python's `for` loop (though only used here with integers?) — but it borrows at least as many constructs from other languages:

1. The `do` … `end` delimiters from Ruby.
2. From Smalltalk and Ruby, method arguments are simply listed with whitespace separation after the method name instead of being delimited with punctuation.
3. The language for some reason seems unable to handle `a.b.c` despite the order of operations having been left-to-right for such expressions at least since the release of C in around 1970. Instead this odd language makes you type `{a.b}.c` unless I misunderstand a special case here.
4. Lambda functions use parens and an arrow.
5. Regular expressions have direct support in the syntax, using `r/.../`.

For those who cannot see the image clearly, here is a snippet from it showing all of the above five features (this occurs one level deep, inside curly braces whose beginning we cannot see:

```
def __init__(self parent: nil) do
    {super}.__init__ parent;
    self.setLayout {QGridLayout};

    transform = (t) -> {r/([^>])\n/.sub '\]<br />' t};

    for c in (0 4) {self.layout}.setRowStretch    c 1;
    for c in (0 3) {self.layout}.setColumnStretch c 1;

    {self.layout}.addWidget {QLabel {transform self.text}} 1 1;
    {self.layout}.addLayout {
        sublayout = {QHBoxLayout};
        sublayout.addWidget {QLineEdit};
        sublayout.addWidget {QPushButton '<…Russian text…>'};
        return sublayout;
    } 2 1;
    {self.layout}.addWidget {QLabel {transform self.footer}} 3 1;
end;
```

My wild guess is that this language compiles directly to C++, since beneath the pretty syntax I see nothing here that requires a dynamic language.

Comment: On the original image you can see, that processed output is piped directly to “normal” python interpreter, so it doesn't compile to C++. It seems that after processing this tool yields standard python code. And second example shows us the way to directly interpret this language.

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer is not useful to me, but at least it is far better than simple “this is waste of time”… (;

Comment: I figured that the Python converted and compiled the back-end language in one step; but my guess could *very* easily be wrong, and your guess is definitely the better one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `-m` flag to `python` refers to a module `dg.py`. (Try `python -m this` which is like saying `import this` on the python shell.)

Looks like `dg.py` is a interpreter for some custom language. The top half of your image looks like a code snippet in this "`dg`" language. It's running on KDE, and seems to use the Qt library.  Can't find it online though.

Comment: Yes, I know what -m flag does. My question was exactly about dg module.  I thought that it must be some wide known project, because it looks very promising. But it can be some unpublished work-in-progress thing, too.

Answer (score -1):

I think this name('dg') is just rundom. So don't waste your time on such things.

Comment: Well, it is possible. But when we have two different references to this project from different sources, different examples but with same language features… I don't think this project is totally unknown.

Comment: If it has no reference from search engines then it closed and about it know only few people. And that people wouldn't tell you. So this is waste of time.